# ansible based wordpress installation not working

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, ansible, ansible-2.x

Hope y'all are enjoying the holidays. I am attempting an automated installation of wordpress on my Linux VM using ansible. To that end, I have written this ansible piece of code that tries to mimic the [official ubuntu guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview).

Here is the code:

```
- name: "Installing wordpress dependencies"
  hosts: all
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
    get_installer: 'curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o /tmp/composer-setup.php || /bin/true'
    get_signature: 'curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig'
  tasks:
        - name: "Update repository"
          apt: 
              update_cache: "yes"
        - name: "Installing requirements"
          apt:
            name:
                 - "curl"
                 - "php"
                 - "php-cli"
                 - "gnupg"
                 - "unzip"
                 - "mysql-server"
                 - "php-fpm"
                 - "php-mysql"
                 - "apache2"
                 - "ghostscript"
                 - "libapache2-mod-php"
                 - "php-bcmath"
                 - "php-curl"
                 - "php-imagick"
                 - "php-intl"
                 - "php-json"
                 - "php-mbstring"
                 - "php-xml"
                 - "php-zip"
            state: present
        - name: Populate service facts
          ansible.builtin.service_facts:
        - name: Print service facts
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            var: ansible_facts.services
        - name: "stopping nginx if running"
          service:
            name: nginx
            state: stopped
          when: "'nginx' in ansible_facts.services"
        - name: "remove nginx if installed"
          apt:
            name:
                - "nginx"
            state: absent
        - name: stop Mysql
          service:
            name: mysql
            state: stopped
          when: "'mysql' in ansible_facts.services"
        - name: stop apache2
          service:
            name: apache2
            state: stopped
          when: "'apache2' in ansible_facts.services"

- name: Installing wordpress through source
  hosts: all
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    wprootdir: "/srv/www/wordpress"
  tasks:
    - name: checking if wp src dir exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ wprootdir }}"
      register: dir_details
    - name: delete existing wordpress source files
      become_user: www-data
      no_log: True
      file:
        #path: "{{ item.path }}"
        #recurse: True
        path: "{{ wprootdir }}"
        state: absent
      #with_items: "{{ path_list.files }}"
    - name: creating /var/www for wordpress source
      file:
        #path: "'{{ wp-root-dir }}' + 'wordpress'" 
        path: "/srv/www/wordpress" 
        recurse: yes
        state: directory
        owner: www-data
        mode: '0755'  
    - name: downloading and extracting wordpress source
      shell:
        cmd: "curl https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz | sudo -u www-data tar zx -C /srv/www"
      register: status
    - fail:
        msg: "Unable to download or extract wordpress source"
      when: (status.rc != 0)

- name: Configuring apache for wordpress
  hosts: all
  become: True
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    wprootdir: "/srv/www/wordpress"
    wpconffile: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf"
  tasks:
    - name: deleting the file if it exists
      file:
        path: "{{ wpconffile }}"
        state: absent
    - name: creating wordpress conf file
      file:
        path: "{{ wpconffile }}"
        state: touch
        owner: www-data
    - name: populating wordpress conf file
      template:
        src: apache2.j2
        dest: "{{ wpconffile }}"
    - name: enabling the site
      shell:
        cmd: "a2ensite wordpress"
    - name: enable URL rewriting
      shell:
        cmd: "a2enmod rewrite"
    - name: disable default "it works" site
      shell:
        cmd: "a2dissite 000-default"
    - name: restart apache2
      service:
        name: apache2
        state: reloaded

- name: Configuring database
  hosts: all
  become: True
  gather_facts: True
  #gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    mysql_port: 3306
    mysql_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    mysql_superuser: root
    mysql_superuser_home: "{% if mysql_superuser == 'root' %}/root{% else %}/home/{{ mysql_superuser }}{% endif %}"
    mysql_superuser_password: SuperUserPwd
    mysql_wordpress_password: WordpressPwd
    http_port: 80  
  tasks:
    - name: Installing PyMySql through pip
      pip:
        name: PyMySql
        state: present
    - name: ensure mysql is running and starts on boot
      service:
        name: mysql
        state: started
        enabled: True
          
    - name: Removes anonymous user account for localhost
      community.mysql.mysql_user:
        name: ''
        state: absent
        login_user: root
        login_password: ""
        login_unix_socket: "{{ mysql_socket }}"
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is undefined      

    - name: adding a password for root user
      mysql_user:
        # Update the superuser to have all grants and a password
        name: "{{ mysql_superuser }}"
        host: localhost
        password: "{{ mysql_superuser_password }}"
        priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
        # Login *as root* to perform this change, even though you might
        # be altering the root user itself
        login_user: root
        login_password: ""
        login_port: "{{ mysql_port }}"
        login_host: localhost
        login_unix_socket: "{{ mysql_socket }}"
        # As a good measure,have ansible check whether an implicit login
        # is possible first
        check_implicit_admin: yes
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is undefined      
    - name: "Create custom fact directory"
      file:
        path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
        state: "directory"
        recurse: yes
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is undefined      
    - name: "record mysql info in custom fact"
      template:
        src: mysqlinfo.j2
        dest: /etc/ansible/facts.d/mysqlinfo.fact
        mode: 0644
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is undefined      
    - name: "re-run setup to use custom facts"
      setup:
        filter: ansible_local
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is undefined      
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "mysqlinfo is {{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo }}"
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is defined
        
        #- name: Create system-wide mysql configuration file
        #template:
        #src: mysql_sys.cnf.j2
        #dest: /etc/my.cnf

        #- name: Create mysql configuration file for `{{ mysql_superuser }}`
        #template:
        #src: mysql_superuser.cnf.j2
        #dest: "{{ mysql_superuser_home }}/.my.cnf"

    - name: create database wordpress
      mysql_db: 
        db: wordpress
        state: present
        login_user: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser }}"
        login_password: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser_password }}"
        login_unix_socket: "{{ mysql_socket }}"
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is defined

    - name: Create database user 'wordpress' with all database privileges
      community.mysql.mysql_user:
        name: wordpress
        password: "{{ mysql_wordpress_password }}"
        login_user: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser }}"
        login_password: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser_password }}"
        priv: '*.*:ALL'
        state: present
      when: ansible_local.mysqlinfo is defined

    - name: Flush privileges
      mysql_query:
        login_db: wordpress
        login_user: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser }}"
        login_password: "{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_superuser_password }}"
        login_unix_socket: "{{ mysql_socket }}"
        query: FLUSH PRIVILEGES 

     # UFW Configuration
    - name: "UFW - Allow HTTP on port {{ http_port }}"
      ufw:
        rule: allow
        port: "{{ http_port }}"
        proto: tcp
      notify:
      - Restart Mysql
      tags: [ system ]

  handlers:
    - name: Restart Mysql
      service:
        name: mysql
        state: restarted
    - name: Restart Apache2
      service:
        name: apache2
        state: restarted

- name: Configuring wordpress to connect to the database
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  become: true
  vars:
    wpconfigfile: "/srv/www/wordpress/wp-config.php"
  tasks:
    - name: copy sample config to wp-config.php
      #become_user: www-data
      copy:
        remote_src: yes
        src: /srv/www/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php
        dest: "{{ wpconfigfile }}"
        owner: www-data

    - name: "re-run setup to use custom facts"
      setup:
        filter: ansible_local
    - name: set database credentials in the config file
      become: false
      #become_user: www-data
      #become_method: "su"
      # multiple commands are run like this whereas with
      # single command one can use a cmd paramater
      # since this is technically *not* a list passed to /bin/sh
      # we do not need a list here. Instead it is a series of 
      # commands being passed to /bin/sh
      #shell: |
      # apparently, passing this list directly doesn't seem to work
      # what works is this loop
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "sudo -u www-data sed -i s/database_name_here/wordpress/ {{ wpconfigfile }}"
        - "sudo -u www-data sed -i s/username_here/wordpress/ {{ wpconfigfile }}"
        - "sudo -u www-data sed -i s/password_here/{{ ansible_local.mysqlinfo.mysql_wordpress_password }}/ {{ wpconfigfile }}"
    - name: get random secret keys
      uri:
        url: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
        return_content: yes
        body_format: json
      register: wordpress_keys
    - debug:
        var: wordpress_keys.content
    - name: delete existing bak file
      file:
        path: "{{ wpconfigfile }}.bak"
        state: absent
    - name: run script to remove key placeholders
      become_user: www-data
      script:
        chdir: /srv/www/wordpress/
        cmd: replacelines.py
        executable: /usr/bin/python3
        environment: /srv/www/wordpress/
    - name: update config file
      become_user: www-data
      copy:
        remote_src: yes
        src: "{{ wpconfigfile }}.bak"
        dest: "{{ wpconfigfile }}"
    - blockinfile:
        path: "{{ wpconfigfile }}"
        marker: // {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK  
        # having this separator here was giving me issues   
        #block: |
        block:
          "{{ wordpress_keys.content }}"

  handlers:
    - name: Restart Mysql
      service:
        name: mysql
        state: restarted
    - name: Restart Apache2
      service:
        name: apache2
        state: restarted
```

Associated jinja2 template files are here:

Apache2 template:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername {{ ansible_hostname }}
    DocumentRoot "{{ wprootdir }}"
    <Directory "{{ wprootdir }}">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "{{ wprootdir }}/wp-content">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

mysqlinfo template

```
{
    "mysql_port": "{{ mysql_port }}",
    "mysql_socket": "{{ mysql_socket }}",
    "mysql_superuser": "{{ mysql_superuser }}",
    "mysql_superuser_password": "{{ mysql_superuser_password }}",
    "mysql_wordpress_password": "{{ mysql_wordpress_password }}"
}
```

replacelines.py script:

```
import re

with open("wp-config.php", "r") as wpconfig, open("wp-config.php.bak", "w") as wpconfigbak:
    for line in wpconfig:
        found = re.search(r'AUTH_KEY|SECURE_AUTH_KEY|LOGGED_IN_KEY|NONCE_KEY|AUTH_SALT|SECURE_AUTH_SALT|LOGGED_IN_SALT|NONCE_SALT', line.strip());
        if (not found):
            wpconfigbak.write(line)
        else:
            continue
```

inventory file:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

With this playbook I am able to see the wordpress landing page when I open 'localhost:80/' on my Linux machine. However I am unable to get to the wordpress dashboard. I run the playbook like so: `ansible-playbook -i inventory SetupWordpress.yaml`

To save time, you may use my github repo:

```
git clone -b WIP git@github.com:redbilledpanda/DevOpsScripts.git
cd DevOpsScripts && ansible-playbook -i inventory SetupWordpress.yaml
```

After the playbook completes, I go to `http://localhost:80` and I am presented with the installer:
[image]

I fill in the details:
[image]

Apparently, it succeeds:
[image]

When I try logging in, I don't see the dashboard. Instead, I never go past the login screen (it doesn't say incorrect credentials or anything though):
[image]

I am at a loss as to what am I doing wrong. Keen to hear from you folks.

***UPDATE1:*** If I skip the part where I generate the wordpress 'salts'/keys it works. I can see the dashboard etc. With these salts however, it just won't get to the wordpress admin dashboard.

Comment: So, the libraries are successfully installed, the services are properly started, you are able to interact with the wordpress portal; how is this an ansible issue? do you have logs from wordpress? are there any errors reported there? Not sure that this question has the right tags

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas  If I use wordpress 'salts' aka randomly generated keys, I just can't get to the wordpress dashboard. I've tried the steps manually and it works. The same when tried using ansible automation doesn't. So either I'm not doing the ansible part right or perhaps it has got something to do with wordpress. Hence the tags

Comment: So it is all about `register: wordpress_keys` and writing the content of it into a file?

Comment: @U880D  That's what I'm doing to write the runtime 'salts' into the file. If I do that, I cannot connect to the wordpress backend it seems

Answer (score 0):

Using a minimal sample config file `wpconfig.file`

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 * ...
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 * ...
 */
```

and a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Get random secret keys
    uri:
      url: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
      return_content: yes
      body_format: json
    register: wordpress_keys

  - name: Show keys
    debug:
      var: wordpress_keys.content

  - name: Write keys to config
    blockinfile:
      path: wpconfig.file
      marker: // {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
      block:
        "{{ wordpress_keys.content }}"
```

it results into the expected and probably correct output.

```yaml
TASK [Show keys] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  wordpress_keys.content: |-
    define('AUTH_KEY',         '...');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '...');
    define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '...');
    define('NONCE_KEY',        '...');
    define('AUTH_SALT',        '...');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '...');
    define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '...');
    define('NONCE_SALT',       '...');
```

```bash
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 * ...
 * Authentication unique keys and salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases! You can generate these using
 * the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}.
 *
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies.
 * This will force all users to have to log in again.
 * ...
 */
// BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
define('AUTH_KEY',         '...');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '...');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '...');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '...');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '...');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '...');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '...');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '...');
// END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

**Summary**

- Your current question and description seems not to be focused on the necessary part but on everything not so related around
- On Ansible tasks I am not able to (re-)produce an issue
- The part deals with configuration for a 3rd party web service or PHP only
- According this it seems not to be related to Ansible at all
- The problem domain seems to be Wordpress and PHP setup and configuration only, namely the config file
- For further troubleshooting you may try to [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html), the config file including keys generated `define('AUTH_KEY',         '{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_letters length=64') }}');`
- Check with Browser in Incognito Mode because of invalidated cookies
- Therefore it is also not about programming at all
- An other site on Stack like serverfault.com, superuser.com, devops.staexchange.com or wordpress.stackexchange.com might fit better for your question

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. So is it possible that I am trying to re-generate the keys everytime? Perhaps you think using a 'template' instead of a block in file would be better? I did try reposting it on server fault but it looks like it belongs to devops site. Would love to hear more from you before I move it over there. Thanks

Comment: "_Perhaps you think using a 'template' instead of a block in file would be better?_", right, thats the case and because of less dependencies (no internet lookup necessay, no complex lineinfile or blockinfile manipulations.). "_So is it possible that I am trying to re-generate the keys everytime?_", since I am not familiar with Wordpress, PHP, etc at all, I can't answer that.

Answer (score -1):

-regenerate the security keys

-Make sure the keys are entered correctly in the wp-config file of your WordPress installation.

Comment: this should happen on the fly when the wp-config file is getting populated right? should be re-used if them keys are already present. Is this what I am going wrong? have you tried running it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).